# What will happen if Cache-Control have `no-cache` and `max-age=900`?

Tags: caching, proxy, no-cache, fastly, max-age

What'll happen if I set server response as:
`Cache-Control: private,no-cache,max-age=900`? 
What'll happen if the header is like:
`Cache-Control: public,no-cache,max-age=900`?

Since it has a `no-cache` whether browser (Or proxy server) consider the `max-age`?

Answer (score 8):

As stated in the [RFC documents](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1):

> If the no-cache directive does not specify a field-name, then a cache
>   MUST NOT use the response to satisfy a subsequent request without
>   successful revalidation with the origin server. This allows an origin
>   server to prevent caching even by caches that have been configured to
>   return stale responses to client requests.

As a result, if `no-cache` has been defined in a server's response, this means that the browser (and any intermediary caches) will "revalidate" on every request (aka make a request to the origin server and return its response, instead of using any cached content).

So, to clearly answer your question:

> Since it has a no-cache whether browser (Or proxy server) consider the
>   max-age?

No, the browser will not consider the `max-age` (given that the browser can handle the `no-cache` directive, since this might not recognized by some HTTP 1.0 browsers/caches).